# Combine feature and labels to correctly produce tf dataset for model.fit (Using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0

I have created a model that takes an input of shape (None, 512). Below is the summary of my model

[image]

#### shape of training feature

```
train_ids.shape
(10, 512)
```

#### shape of the training response variable

```
indus_cat_train.shape
(10, 49)
```

My model runs perfectly if I use

```
history = model.fit(
    train_ids, indus_cat_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(
        valid_ids, indus_cat_valid))
```

#### However my actual dataset is very large and feeding the completed dataset all at once is consuming so much RAM and shut down all the process.

I want to feed all data in batches or one by one. In order to complete this task, I tried out tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices function

```
# training data
tf_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_ids, indus_cat_train))

# validation data
tf_valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_ids, indus_cat_valid))
```

The above code is running fine and upon inspection, it is giving the desired shape

```
for elem in t:
    print(elem[0].shape) # for features
    print(elem[1].shape) # for response
```

print output

```
    (512,) # for features
    (49,)  # for response variable
# terminating all other output to save space
```

However on-calling model.fit on tf_train_dataset the model gives me an error

```
bert_history = model.fit(
    tf_train_data, epochs=2, validation_data=tf_valid_data)
```

***WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 512) for input Tensor("input_ids_1:0", shape=(None, 512), dtype=int32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (512, 1).***

Sharing model code for further understanding as asked by Prateek

```
# training data

tf_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_ids, indus_cat_train))

# validation data

tf_valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_ids, indus_cat_valid))





# model downloaded from bert

bert_model_name = "uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12"

bert_ckpt_dir = "bert_model"

bert_ckpt_file = os.path.join(bert_ckpt_dir, "bert_model.ckpt")

bert_config_file = os.path.join(bert_ckpt_dir, "bert_config.json")



# creating tokenizer

tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=os.path.join(bert_ckpt_dir, "vocab.txt"))



# create function for model

def create_model(max_seq_len, bert_ckpt_file, n_classes):

    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(bert_config_file, "r") as reader:

        # get bert configurations

        bert_configurations = StockBertConfig.from_json_string(reader.read())

        bert_params = map_stock_config_to_params(bert_configurations)

        bert_params_adapter_size = None

        bert = BertModelLayer.from_params(bert_params, name="bert")



    input_ids = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_len,), dtype="int32",

                                   name="input_ids")



    bert_output = bert(input_ids)

    print("bert shape", bert_output.shape)



    cls_out = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda seq: seq[:, 0, :])(bert_output)

    cls_out = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(cls_out)

    logits = keras.layers.Dense(units=765, activation="tanh")(cls_out)

    logits = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(logits)

    logits = keras.layers.Dense(

        units=n_classes, activation="softmax")(logits)



    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_ids, outputs=logits)

    model.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_len))

    load_stock_weights(bert, bert_ckpt_file)

    return model





n_cats = 49 #number of output categories

model = create_model(max_seq_len=512, bert_ckpt_file=bert_ckpt_file,

                     n_classes=n_cats)



model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(    learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=1e-08)



loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy(    name='categorical_crossentropy')model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])



bert_history = model.fit( tf_train_data, epochs=2, validation_data=tf_valid_data)
```

Comment: Could you share your model code? Looks like there is an issue with the input layer. Also, you could batch your input data by using something like this `tf_train_data = tf_train_data .batch(3)`.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt I have updated the code as your requirement. Please let me know in case further information is required. One thing to note down is that this code is working fine when I use a separate NumPy array for features and label data.

Comment: Good that you applied my recommendation of batching your dataset and it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it using dataset.batch. tf.data.Dataset was missing the batch size arguments as a result of which supplied tensors are not batched, i.e. I was getting  shape (512,1) instead of (512,) and (49,1) instead of (49,)

```
batch_size = 2
tf_train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_ids,
                                                    indus_cat_train)).batch(batch_size)
tf_valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_ids,
                                                    indus_cat_valid)).batch(batch_size)

bert_history = model.fit(
    tf_train_data, epochs=2, validation_data=tf_valid_data)
```